# Why is my callback being sent as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sending in a callback to a javascript function and for some reason it's receiving it as a string. I'm using node.js, if that matters.

```
execProg('runCheck','data=data1',
    function (error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log("isWorking");
    });

execProg = function (args,callback){ 
    var cmdString = 'php -f '+pathprefix+'processing.php '+args;
    console.log(typeof callback);
    exec(cmdString, callback);
};
```

This works when I do this:

```
execProg = function (args,callback){ 
    var cmdString = 'php -f '+pathprefix+'processing.php '+args;
    console.log(typeof callback);
    exec(cmdString, function(error, stdout, stderr){console.log("isWorking1"});
};
```

However, when using the callback sent through the function `execProg` parameters, it thinks it's a `string`, as evidenced by the `console.log(typeof callback);`

I've done this countless times, but this time I'm using node.js, and also I could be missing something I just didn't notice, but besides those possibilities, there doesn't seem to be any I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to send 2 params 'runCheck ' and 'data=data1' as one args parameter. Concatenate them into one.

```
execProg('runCheck data=data1',
    function (error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log("isWorking");
});
```